# What does the SysTick code using 24-bit difference mean?

Tags: c, microcontroller, clock, cortex-m

I am new to programming a ARM Cortex M MCU. While using SysTick feature, i came across this function to check the time clocked. However i do not get the code in the 5th line. The one about 24-bit difference. Why did they do a bitwise operator on that line? What is it supposed to do?

```
 unsigned long Last;     // 24-bit time at previous call (12.5ns)
 unsigned long Elapsed;  // 24-bit time between calls (12.5ns)
void Action(void){      // function under test
  Now = NVIC_ST_CURRENT_R;         // what time is it now?
  Elapsed = (Last-Now)&0x00FFFFFF; // 24-bit difference
  Last = Now;                      // set up for next...
}
```

Comment: It is a 24 bit counter, register size doesnt matter the timer is 24 bits so math on differences has to be clipped to 24 bits.

Comment: Take a 3 bit counter for example  2 - 5 = -3, 0xFFFFFFFD but 5,6,7,0,1,2  is 5 counts away.   (2 - 5) & 7 = 5 which is the difference for a 3 bit counter.   24 bit counter same deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter is 24 bits, but when you read it, you get 32 bits because C doesn't have 24-bit variables (at least not with this compiler).

They are doing a 24-bit subtraction, by doing a 32-bit subtraction and then setting the extra 8 bits to 0.

It's important to set the extra bits to 0, because after 16777215 (all bits set to 1) the counter resets to 0 (all bits set to 0). If you just subtract them, you would see that 1 - 16777215 is -16777214 (signed) or 4278190082 (unsigned), but the correct answer is that 2 ticks happened in between tick 16777215 and tick 1.

Comment: Why decimal numbers and why signed? There is no signed arithmetic here.

Comment: `C doesn't have 24-bit variables (at least not with this compiler).` it has. They are called bitfields.

Comment: @P__J__ You can't have  bitfield variables.

Comment: @user253751 i understand what you mean. Another thing that i would like to clarify on the side is if the RELOAD register value is n, period of clock is 12.5ns, then the limitation of it is that it can only be accurate up to (12.5*n) nanoseconds. If so, why are people still using this as a clock? It seems to have limited use to me.

Comment: @Shane That means it repeats about every 0.2 seconds. But maybe they don't need better timing than that? As long as you check it at least once every 0.2 seconds, you can add extra bits your own extra bits in software, by counting the number of times it goes back to 0. There might even be an interrupt you can use to detect when it goes back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because Last & Elapsed have 24 bits (3 bytes) of the meaningful data, but they are 32bit (4 bytes) you need to zero the most significant 8 bits.

The `... & 0x00ffffff` does it.

You can also

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t cnt:24;
}SYSTICK_cnt_t;


uint32_t GetElapsed(uint32_t Now, uint32_t Start)
{
    SYSTICK_cnt_t t = {Now - Start};

    return t.cnt;
}
```

Comment: `& 0xffffff` _does it._, typo?  ( should be `0x00ffffff`)

Comment: @ryyker please show me the difference between  `0x0000000000000ffffff`,  `0x00ffffff` and `0xffffff`. Do they have different values?

Comment: You quoted the OP snippet by saying _"The ..._ `& 0xffffff` _does it."_.  If you are going to change the expression used in the post, even if it is equivalent, and especially when you are quoting it, provide an explanation saying why you changed it, and that they are equivalent.

Comment: Removing the leading zeros is obfuscation in any case.  Clarity is king; keep the zeros and save you and your coworkers' sanity.